# Why is my power supply behaving weirdly when I connect my RF amplifier?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, rf, antenna

I have designed an RF power amplifier that operates close to 100 MHz and amplifies signals from 50mW to about 2W. Everytime I switch it on, the voltage on my lab power supply drops even though the current is within limits. It also makes a weird buzzing noise. I realised that the RF signal is finding its way into the power supply(2V peak-peak) inspite of the 1uH choke coil L2 and the decoupling capacitors C7 and C8. Is that why the power amplifier is behaving weirdly. If so how do I solve the problem? Also the problem only occurs if I connect the antenna. I am not sure why that is so too. Could it be because of some kind of impedance mismatch or EMI?

[image: My RF power amplifier]

Comment: Not asn answer, but there might be an output impedance spec of the power source. I am pretty sure that 100 MHz out of bounds for many benchtop sources. There are radio transmitter power sources, that I hear bout in amateur radio communities. (i.e. Reddit)

Sometimes ARRL Handbook proves itself very useful in such cases, I am sure that it has a section discussing power sources.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it happens only when I connect the antenna. I mean if I don't connect the antenna but I start sending an input signal, the current draw rises but the voltage doesn't drop. But once I connect the antenna, voltage drops to about 10V even though the current draw doesn't increase.

Comment: Question: Is this in simulation, or in real?

Comment: No, this is real life. Everything is beautiful in simulations.

Comment: Can it be because until you connect the antenna, you do not feed the antenna power, due to the impedance mismatch? When you connect it, you actually transfer power, and start extracting that power from the source. Maybe it will help to use a cable to distance the transmitter to the antenna, but if I had to guess, I would say it is due to droop due to drawing high current, high frequency.

Comment: I must ask to understand, sorry. Did you decouple the RF power amplifier properly?

Comment: Decouple? How? It is a naked PCB sitting on top of my table near the Lab power supply. I have the decoupling capacitors C7 and C8, if that is what you mean. Or do you mean that the EMI from the amplifier is affecting the power supply?

Comment: Yes, such things require a lot of tinkering and looking for changes to understand. I would start by increasing the capacitance, adding clippable chokes on the power supply cables. It is a bit of knowledge+alchemy there.

Comment: In order to get the answer without tinkering a lot, what you need is a LISN, and a spectrum analyzer. The simplest thing to do might be also to borrow a better power supply to test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78238/discussion-between-kevin-selva-prasanna-and-mehmet-ali-anil).

Comment: You haven't said if your supply is switched or linear, but whilst building a linear supply recently I experienced something similar to what you are describing and it turned out to be oscillations in the supply control element.  I'm guessing that the consequence of the RF finding its way back to the supply is that it's oscillating.  But, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I think it is a switched mode power supply. It is a huge 8kg lab power supply. This is the product page http://www.scientificindia.com/products/PSD3304-30V2A-0-to-15V1A-5V5A-Multiple-Power-Supply.aspx

Comment: I would try increasing L2 and C5.  As per Andy's answer to your earlier question, L2 is acting as an RF choke and C5 provides an AC path to ground.  You'll have to experiment a bit, I'm in the middle of building something similar myself!